PyInstaller temporary files error when updating
My problem is similar to that described in the linked question. Inno Setup PyInstaller Auto-Update
I want to create an automatic update mechanism for my PyQt PyInstaller application.
My program downloads the installer (Inno Setup) from the server, runs it, and then immediately closes. The installer then installs a new version of my program, after which it should start automatically. However, instead of starting, my program fails with the error "Failed to load Python DLL 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI278082\python3.10.dll.'."
For some reason, Pyinstaller exe is trying to access temporary files that were deleted after the first version of my application closed.
Let me give an example:

myProg.exe starts and creates a temporary folder '_MEI123'
myProg closes, and the '_MEI123' folder is deleted
The installer replaces myProg with the new version
When myProg starts, it tries to access '_MEI123', which no longer exists

It is important to note that if you run the application manually, there are no errors at startup. If you run the installer manually, my program also runs automatically after installation without errors.
I have tried running the application after installation using both Inno (start after installation) and CMD commands:
subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe', '/c', fr'{installer_path} /silent && {exe_path}'], creationflags=0x00000008 | 0x00000200)

Both of these options returned an error.
If you manually call the command through the console:
start /wait "C:\Users\user\myProg_setup.exe" /silent && "C:\Users\user\myProg.exe" 
There are also no errors.
That is, somehow, the reason for this error is that the installer for my application was started by my own application. So far, the only solution that has worked is to install the file with a different name. However, this option is not ideal for me.
EDIT:
Minimal reproducible example:
main.py
import subprocess
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

def update():                                               #path to same exe
    subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe", "/c", r"timeout /t 2 && C:\pytest\dist\main.exe"], creationflags=0x00000008 | 0x00000200, close_fds = True)
    app.quit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = QPushButton('Click me!')
button.clicked.connect(update)
button.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

Build it with
pyinstaller .\main.py --onefile --noconsole
Run main.exe and press the button
The temporary files that I mentioned are the Python interpreter, which is created implicitly by PyInstaller when you run the executable.
Updating the executable file, as I found out, does not seem to play a significant role, so I left only the delayed launch of the same program.
In fact, even with flags, the Popen function still cannot create a completely isolated instance from the parent process. The instance of my program that is running in Popen believes that the parent instance of the program is still active, so it attempts to access the interpreter of the parent program. However, at this point, the interpreter has already been closed. This is just a hypothesis on my part, and i may be mistaken.
